# Maximum and Minimum on nested subquery

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm working on Libray Management System. I've a few tables among which i have `Member_master` and `Book_issue_details` tables.

`Book_issue_tables` contains details like `book_id`, `member_id` and `book issue date`, `return date`, etc.

I need to retrieve name and count of books for those members who have been issued maximum and minimum number of books.

I'm able to retrieve name and number of books with a simple group by query. But i'm getting clueless over how to retrieve max and min over the retrieved resultset. Correlated subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `HAVING` clause that filters the groups using [Subqueries with `ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/all-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT   name, COUNT(*)
FROM     Book_issue_details
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT(*) <= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book_issue_details GROUP BY name)
      OR COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book_issue_details GROUP BY name)
```